# Summary table query

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the query below:

```
SELECT territory,
       ( CASE
             WHEN content_type_cat IN ('A',
                                       'AB',
                                       'AC') THEN 'ABC'
             ELSE 'XYZ'
         END ) AS content_type,
       count(DISTINCT customerid) AS unique_customers
FROM table.table1
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-05-09' AND '2016-07-18'
  AND content_type_cat IN ('A',
                           'AB',
                           'AC',
                           'D',
                           'E')
  AND one_more_column NOT IN ('alpha',
                              'beta',
                              'gamma')
GROUP BY 1,
         2;
```

Can you please help me modify this query to get the following report:

```
date| Territory| content_type|no_unique_customers_30_days
```

Comment: Whatever you used to edit that query messed with the single quotes, you won't want to use that editor for SQL because it will cause errors.

Comment: This `no_unique_customers_30_days` should be the count of unique customers within the last 30 days for each date? How big is this table/How many rows are returned by this WHERE-condition?

Comment: This no_unique_customers_30_days should be the count of unique customers within the last 30 days for each date? Yes.

Comment: How big is this table/How many rows are returned by this WHERE-condition? About 250 rows.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information about the relationship between the `date` column in your table and result set (are they the same?) and the `30_days` you want the customers counted over.  For your date '2016-05-09', do you want customers counted 30 days before that date?  So your `where` clause is actually excluding customers you want counted?

Answer (score 2):

Use a case expression within the aggregate function based on the range you want (often called a "conditional aggregate")

```
SELECT
      territory
    , (
      CASE
            WHEN content_type_cat IN ('A', 'AB', 'AC') THEN 'ABC'
            ELSE 'XYZ'
      END
      ) AS content_type
    , COUNT(DISTINCT
               CASE
                   WHEN date >= current_date - 30 
                    AND date < current_date THEN customerid
               END
      ) AS unique_customers_30_days
FROM table1
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-05-09' AND '2016-07-18'
AND content_type_cat IN ('A', 'AB', 'AC', 'D', 'E')
AND one_more_column NOT IN ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')
GROUP BY 1 , 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I cannot use current_date...I need the date, and the number of unique customers in last 30 days for that date. So 2016-05-09|number of customers between 2016-04-10 and 2016-05-09

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(Date),   --MIN(DATE) 
      territory,
     (
      CASE
            WHEN content_type_cat IN ('A', 'AB', 'AC') THEN 'ABC'
                 ELSE 'XYZ'
      END
      ) AS content_type,
     COUNT(DISTINCT
               CASE
                   WHEN date >= current_date - 30 
                    AND date < current_date THEN customerid
               END
      ) AS unique_customers_30_days
FROM table1
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-05-09' AND '2016-07-18'
AND content_type_cat IN ('A', 'AB', 'AC', 'D', 'E')
AND one_more_column NOT IN ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')
GROUP BY 2,3;
```

Comment: please format your request (very hard to read as-is) and elaborate a bit. code only answers might be considered as low quality, and hence removed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is based on a non-equi-self-join which might create a big intermediate result before aggregation. If the number of rows is small it's still efficient:

```
WITH cte AS
 ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT territory,
       ( CASE
             WHEN content_type_cat IN ('A',
                                       'AB',
                                       'AC') THEN 'ABC'
             ELSE 'XYZ'
         END ) AS content_type,
         customerid
   FROM TABLE.table1
   WHERE content_type_cat IN ('A',
                              'AB',
                              'AC',
                              'D',
                              'E')
   AND one_more_column NOT IN ('alpha',
                               'beta',
                               'gamma')
 )  
SELECT t1.territory,
       t1.content_type,
       Count(DISTINCT t2.customerid) AS unique_customers
FROM cte AS t1
JOIN cte AS t2
  ON t2.territory = t1.territory
 AND t2.content_type = t1.content_type
 -- returns all matching row in the 30 day time frame
 AND t2.datecol BETWEEN t1.datecol-29 AND t1.datecol 
GROUP BY 1,
         2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I tried this and got the error: t2.datecol does not exist. I then added datecol to the cte table as well as the select statement. However this resulted in the query timing out. I do think the intermediate table is too large for this solution to be viable. There are millions of customerids...Are there other approaches we can use here please? Thank you again for your time!

Comment: @samajavaragamana: Ups, correct, I forgot the date column. Btw, I asked for the number of rows returned by the WHERE-condition and you wrote: 250, which is way less than millions :-)  How many rows are returned by the cte? Can you add some more info to yor question like number of territory\content_type\date combinations? Can you create Volatile Tables?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, sorry I'm confused...250 is indeed the number of rows returned by the where condition in the query I originally posted. In that query we select territory, content type and count distinct customerid. However in the query you suggested, we select personid (not count distinct or count), therefore it is running into millions...I'm not very experienced with sql as you can see, so pardon any misinterpretation...

Comment: a. How many rows are returned by the cte? The query was taking too long and got aborted. There are millions of customers...b. Can you add some more info to yor question like number of territory\content_type\date combinations? There are about 200 territories, 2 content types + 1 (Total), date combinations - after 1/1/2017. c.Can you create Volatile Tables? yes

Comment: @samajavaragamana: I meant how many rows are returned by the *Select within the cte*?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
select
    enddate,
    startdate,
    t.territory,
    content_type,
    min(t.date) as min_date,
    max(t.date) as max_date,
    count(distinct t.customerid) as count_customer
from
    (select
      date as endDate,
      date-30 as startDate,
      content_type_cat,
      territory,
      (CASE 
         WHEN content_type_cat IN ('A','AB','AC') THEN 'ABC' 
         ELSE 'XYZ' -- content_type_cat IN ('D','E')
       END ) AS content_type,
      customerid
    from
      db.table
    where
      date BETWEEN '2016-05-09' AND '2016-07-18'
      AND content_type_cat IN ('A','AB','AC','D','E')
      AND one_more_column NOT IN ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')  ) d inner join
    (select * 
     from
       db.table
     where
      date BETWEEN '2016-05-09' - 30 AND '2016-07-18'
      AND content_type_cat IN ('A','AB','AC','D','E')
      AND one_more_column NOT IN ('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma') ) t on
    t.date >= startdate and
    t.date <= enddate and
    t.territory = d.territory and
    t.content_type_cat = d.content_type_cat and
    t.customerid = d.customerid -- and join more columns?  not sure how to identify rows you want counted
where
    endDate BETWEEN '2016-05-09' AND '2016-07-18' 
group by
    1,2,3,4
```

but you really need to understand the relationship between the row you want to use as the end date and the related set of rows from 30 days before.